# r shiny textAreaInput html

Tags: html, r, shiny

I am trying to get shiny's textAreaInput function to display html text as default, however I cannot seem to do so.

I know it is possible to render html text in the UI, but am not sure how to get textAreaInput's value parameter to render HTML.

My minimal example is below:

```
library(shiny)

example_html <- HTML('<p><b>foo</b></p>')

ui <- fluidPage(
    textAreaInput('dummy', label = 'dummy', value = example_html)
)

server=function(input,output){

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure what you really want. If you want to display HTML, you are better off with the functions `uiOutput` and `renderUI`

Comment: why do you want an Input element to render HTML. This sound like an abuse of an Input element or could please explain you use case!

Comment: I want to use textArea to generate an email template that users can then write an email from, and therefore need to input httml to structure the text properly

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can apply the style to individual lines of a text area but you can style the whole box using css. By using the `tags$head`, `tags$style` and `HTML` functions/shiny tags you can apply styles to the text area.

First preview your page and use your web browser element inspector to get the `textarea` element, `.form-control` class or `dummy` id selector tag.  Then insert your selector, along with the css style into your code:

```
example_txt <- HTML('foo')

ui <- fluidPage(

    tags$head(tags$style(HTML('textarea{font-weight: bold;}'))),
    #tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.form-control{font-weight: bold;}'))), # This also works
    #tags$head(tags$style(HTML('#dummy{font-weight: bold;}'))), # This also works

    textAreaInput('dummy', label = 'dummy', value = example_txt ),
)
```

Credit to solutions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43982515/5579281) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37299152/5579281).

Answer (score 0):

Fot he Use case that you mentioned in the comments having an editor that the user can style with HTML the `textAreaInput` won't be enougth you want to include some WYSIWYG (what you see is what you get) editor like tinyMCE.

You will find an example here for example

https://iheart.shinyapps.io/shinyMCE-01-basic/

Hope this helps!!